# Does ios mdm app can help to make network call in all states (Killed/Background)

Tags: ios

I want to make network call in every 10 minutes from my app in all states like (Killed, Background).

I know this is not possible in simple iOS app (Specially in Killed state), can we achieve this using MDM  enabled app?

Comment: If by MDM enabled app you mean an enterprise app, then you may be able to abuse a background mode to keep your app alive since you don't go through review, but it is much better to do things properly and use a push notification or some other event-driven process. Even an enterprise app can be killed by the user

Comment: Yes, it would be Enterprise app, app not going to review by apple. that is fine if it works with event driven process like push notification, but how we can make API call in killed state?

Comment: One more thing, this app has also socket connection capability, if app is in killed state, can i make some request using socket connection from app to server? i want send some text to my server on every hours.